# Big Query: How to join 2 tables on user ID when 1 table contains an array of user ids?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, inner-join

There are somewhat similar answers already posted on StackOverflow, but they didn't address this specific case or involved a query that I was not able to understand, given that I just started my first SQL-related position.

This is the first time I try to join tables having a column values in one of the tables I am joining on in the form of an array. After trying to solve my own problem, I run into the following error: `No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<INT64>, STRING`.

I have 2 tables that look like the following:

Table 1:

```
team_id     user_id
   1       [1, 2, 3]
   2       [4, 5, 6]
   3       [7, 8, 9]
   4      [10, 11, 12]
```

Table 2:

```
user_id    value
   2         10
   5         20
   7         30
   12        40
```

What I want to join Table 2 to Table 1 by way of having Table 2 analyze if there is a matching user_id in an array of Table 1. If there is, then join based on common user_id and output results as follows:

Desired Output

```
team_id  user_id  value
1          2       10
2          5       20
3          7       30
4          12      40
```

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: what if more than one user from table2 matches team_id in table1?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am currently trying to implement the posted answer, but if you have time, I would love to see how tables can be joined in case when more than 1 user from table2 matches team_id in table1

Comment: `I would love to see how ...` - sure. see my answer for this. consider voting up if it helped anyhow :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I will look into it later today after my work. Thank you for sharing your knowledge, as always. I will get back to you shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on `unnest()`:

```
select t1.team_id, t2.user_id, t2.value
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.user_id in unnest(t1.user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT team_id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(t2.user_id IGNORE NULLS) user_id,
  IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) value
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t, t.user_id AS user_id
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING(user_id)
GROUP BY team_id
```

You can test, play with above using sample data similar to yours in question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 team_id, [1, 2, 3] user_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [4, 5, 6] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, [7, 8, 9] UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, [10, 11, 12] UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, [13, 14]
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 2 user_id, 10 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 40 
)
SELECT team_id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(t2.user_id IGNORE NULLS) user_id,
  IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) value
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t, t.user_id AS user_id
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING(user_id)
GROUP BY team_id
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Mikhail, thank you for this example! As promised, I took time today to go through this code and really understand it. It was very helpful to learn about the IFNULL() function I have never used previously, and now I know it is used to avoid zero-based error of a query. I have also noticed how you added an additional corner case of how to deal with cases where user_id is not found in the other table. You are always among first to answer my questions, thank you for that!

I noticed from your example that even though I have an array for a common column, JOIN syntax doesn't change from usual.